# macports tex install does not have nag.sty

Tags: mac, macports

How do I install missing style files with macports' tex install?

```
 File `nag.sty' not found.
```

Comment: I'm guess 'Just use MacTeX' is not the answer you want :-) You might consult http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files, which is basically the same concept.

Comment: I agree, I don't think it makes much sense to try to use macports to install texlive even if it is possible. Just go to http://www.tug.org/mactex/ and grab one zip file, and you will have everything you need, *much* faster.

Comment: Why's everyone hating on MacPorts?

Comment: I don't think it's about _hating_ MacPorts.  It's just that for this purpose, installing MacTeX is probably a much more straightforward procedure than building TeX from scratch.  Also, it's the distribution that 'everyone' uses, so answers will be easier to come by.  Myself, I don't like the way that MacPorts wants to build _everything_ for itself, even when a system version exists.  I understand the rationale, but it grates nonetheless (I've heard of [homebrew](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) as an alternative, but haven't used it)

Comment: Norman, I totally agree.  I chose macports because that's what I use to install svn, gcc44, etc.

I installed mactex, but I'm not sure how to get at pdflatex from the terminal.  Any ideas?

Comment: Should just work: certainly does for me

Comment: @Neil G: I've got pdflatex in `/usr/texbin`, so you'd have to add that directory to the PATH.  I think I've got a standard installation of MacTeX; having said that, I think I would have stopped the installer editing my shell *rc files, so I imagine I decided to add that to the path by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `texlive` from the MacPorts, there is a packet manager `tlmgr` that allows you to install missing packages. If you are using something else, Joseph's comment points in the correct directions.

Comment: how do I install tlmgr?

Comment: I think it should be part of the `texlive` install from MacPorts, i.e. `sudo port install texlive` should do the deal. The program will then be in `/opt/local/bin`, I presume. Comprehensive information about its *usage* is available from [the MacTex wiki](http://mactex-wiki.tug.org/wiki/index.php/TeX_Live_Manager).