# What are the differences between the many LaTeX versions available for OS X?

Tags: mac

There are **many** ways to get LaTeX on an OS X box. I prefer to manage my software via fink, and even then there are a lot of choices. At the time of this writing (2010-08-28) I have the following options:

- texlive (0.20080816-3)
- xetex (0.996-1001)
- tetex (3.0-1006)
- extex (0.0svn8062-1)
- ptex (3.1.11-3)

And I might have missed some. Which of these works best? Which is most up-to-date? Why are there so many?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd simply go to http://www.tug.org/mactex/ and download one zip file and that's everything that you'll need. It includes a complete TeX Live distribution, and also some very useful Mac-specific GUI tools like LaTeXiT.

Fink, MacPorts, etc. may be useful for many things, but getting a complete up-to-date TeX distribution isn't one of those cases. See also [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2172/macports-tex-install-does-not-have-nag-sty) closely related question.

Comment: Good link: I'd agree that for TeX the best approach on the Mac is to use TeX Live directly

Answer (score 6):

Don't use Tetex.  Unfortunately, last time I looked, it was the only Tex supported as a binary by Fink.

Your list misses:

- [Gwtex](http://www.tug.org/twg/mactex/award/2007/gerben/aboutgwtex.html), which is, like Tetex, abandonware, but used to be the nicest Tex install for the Mac.
- [Mactex](http://www.tug.org/twg/mactex/), which is an up-to-date descendant of Gwtex, and is a reasonable alternative to Texlive.

Your best options are Texlive (the 2009 is considered stable, and the 2010 version is usable) or Mactex.  I install Texlive from the ISO image directly to my Mac, and have no problems.  Mactex comes with GUI extras.

Comment: MacTeX isn't just TeX Live with a few extra (independent) Mac applications with the standard TeX binaries in a bizarre location?

Comment: @TH.: The Mactex people say that it is based on Gwtex.  It's certainly very... close to Texlive.  Take a look at Gwtex.  It creates files in all sorts of weird places.

Comment: MacTeX is indeed 'TeX Live + extras'. I use the MacTeX installer for the ability to choose TeX systems from System Prefs., but don't use anything else from MacTeX.

Comment: @Joseph: Mactex is more than a few Mac-specific configuration items and extras thrown into Texlive's multi-platform install.  I should write a postscript saying a bit more about the history and giving some links.  But note, there's also a stand-alone Mactex distribution, Basictex.

Comment: It depends how you do the installation. You can miss out all of the graphical extras if you choose to, at least as far as I can see.

Comment: @Joseph: Sure.  I have Texlive on my Mac without the extras, and installed as generic Unix.  There's no sense in which this installation could count as Mactex.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of ptex or extex until now, but ptex seems to be something related to Japanese LaTeX. I can't find much information on extex. XeTeX is a particular TeX engine that is distributed with recent TeX distributions, so I'm not sure why it's listed separately. teTeX is [old](http://www.tug.org/tetex/) and not updated any longer. TeX Live is what I suggest you use. TeX Live and MiKTeX are the two major TeX distributions. TeX Live 2008 is fairly recent.

Comment: Miktex is Windows only, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think so. I've never used [it](http://miktex.org/unx/about) except once on Windows though.

Comment: @TH.: Miktex-tools isn't a Tex distribution, it's a port of some of the programs developed for Mitex back to Unix.  You could build a Tex distribution around these, but AFAIK, no one has.

Comment: Ah, good to know.

Comment: I'd not call texlive-2008 "fairly recent", when texlive-2010 is being prepared for release (already frozen) `:)`.

Comment: As I recall, TeX Live 2008 was released near the end of December, 2008. Linux distributions were using 2007 for quite a long time. So, "fairly recent" seems about right, especially when compared to teTeX.

Comment: Nope! September, 2008. Not sure what I was thinking of.

Comment: @TH.: Texlive 2009 was released last December, IIRC.

Comment: Ah, that must have been what I was thinking of. It was sort of hard to track down since CTAN doesn't seem to keep old versions around.

Answer (score 2):

[ExTeX](http://www.extex.org) is (was?) a project that aims to create 'typesetting for the 21st century' with a Java-based system derived from TeX (via NTS). It is not finished and in fact seems to be abandoned or at least hybernating (even the nightly builds fail since August last year)